# A lista que eu criei tá apresenta erro java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, lista

Estou tentando solucionar uma parte de um desafio. Nesse desafio eu tenho que percorrer uma lista de comandos, e onde existir "X" na posição e antes dele existir uma letra eu tenho que remover as duas posições da lista. Logo criei o seguinte código:

Para executar esse procedimento eu criei o seguinte código:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Drone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Entre com o comando: ");
        String entrada = sc.nextLine();

        ArrayList<String> posicoes = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(entrada.toUpperCase().split("")));


        //Se tiver um X e antes do tiver uma letra remove o X e a Letra:
        for (int i = 0; i < posicoes.size(); i++) {
            if (posicoes.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("X") && posicoes.get(i-1).matches("[A-Z]*")){
                posicoes.remove(i);
                posicoes.remove(i - 1 );
            }
        }

        for (int j = posicoes.size()-1; j >= 0 ; j--) {
            if (posicoes.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase("X") && posicoes.get(j-1).matches("[A-Z]*")){
                posicoes.remove(j);
                posicoes.remove(j - 1 );
            }

        }






        sc.close();

    }
}
```

**No debug eu consigo obter a resposta, só que no fim da execução ocorre o seguinte erro:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2 at 
java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64) at 
java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70) at 
java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248) at
java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372) at 
java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459) at 
Drone.main(Drone.java:27) Disconnected from the target VM, address:
 '127.0.0.1:49907', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Caso a entrada seja `x` nessa linha `if (posicoes.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("X") && posicoes.get(i-1).matches("[A-Z]*")){` a variável `i` será igual a `0` então fazendo as substruções `if (posicoes.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("X") && posicoes.get(0-1).matches("[A-Z]*")){` essa expressão `posicoes.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("X")` é avaliada como verdadeiro enquanto essa expressão `posicoes.get(0-1).matches("[A-Z]*")` irá gerar o erro que está recebendo pois está tentando acessar um índice negativo numa ArrayList `posicoes.get(0-1)`.

Comment: Qual é a entrada de dados que você está fazendo?

Answer (score 1):

Considerando a entrada:

> AABBXX

O problema no código é que, quando está fazendo a varredura do fim para o começo. Ao remover a ocorrência da `letra + X` você tem que decrementar duas vezes o passo, afinal você não excluiu a atual. Sendo assim, inclua a seguinte linha dentro da sua condição:

```
j -= 1;
```

Além disso, como observado nos comentários, caso o `X` esteja na primeira posição, um erro ocorrerá, afinal você não possui o índice `-1` na lista. Sendo assim, não verifique o índice 0 no seu laço:

```
for (int i = 1; i < posicoes.size(); i++) {
// ...
for (int j = posicoes.size() - 1; j > 0 ; j--) {
```

Veja funcionando aqui no [**ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/Vl5o6l).

---

Você pode ter o mesmo efeito que deseja substituindo cada ocorrência com expressão regular:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Entre com o comando: ");
  String entrada = sc.nextLine();
  Boolean continuar;

  do {
    String resultado = entrada.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z&&[^xX]][xX]", "");
    continuar = !resultado.equals(entrada);
    entrada = resultado;
  } while (continuar);

  System.out.println(entrada);
}
```

Veja funcionando no [**ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/Lpau7q).

No código acima a expressão regular `[a-zA-Z&&[^xX]][xX]`:

- Corresponder a um único caractere presente nas duas listas abaixo `[a-zA-Z&&[^xX]]`:

  - `a-z` corresponde a um único caractere no intervalo entre `a` (índice 97) e `z` (índice 122) (diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas);
  - `A-Z` corresponde a um único caractere no intervalo entre `A` (índice 65) e `Z` (índice 90) (diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas);
  - Corresponder a um único caractere não presente na lista abaixo `[^xX]`.
- `xX` corresponde a um único caractere na lista `xX` (diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas).

---

> [**`replaceAll`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
>
> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Em tradução livre:

> Substitui cada substring dessa string que corresponda a expressão regular informada para substituição.

Comment: O comando de entrada é AABBXX, de acordo com a proposta, esses dois X anularia os dois B, sobrando apenas o AA.

Comment: @WilliamB.Pereira com essa entrada agora a explicação está atualizada.